# Is it possible to draw a normal domain with Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, math-mode

I am trying to draw this kind of image, which is the representation of a normal domain with respect to the x-axis, but I am not very skilled at LaTeX. Is there anyone who knows how to do that?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part gives you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not the most elegant solution, but can perhaps serve as a starting point.

I used `pgfplots` as a basis to draw the coordinate system as well as the "normal domain". Everything is drawn within a single `axis` block. The boundary lines at the top and bottom are created using the `curve through` interpolation functionality from the `hobby` tikzlibrary. Therefore I defined the coordinates (A) to (F) (lower boundary, from left to right) and (G) to (L) (upper boundary, from right to left). Of course, you can adjust the coordinates to your personal preference. For filling the domain I used `pattern=north east lines` from the tikzlibrary `patterns`.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=center, 
              xmin=-1, xmax=8, ymin=-1, ymax=8, 
              line width=1pt, 
              xtick={2, 6}, xticklabels={$a$, $b$}, 
              ytick={2, 6}, yticklabels={},
              xlabel={\normalsize $x$}, xlabel style={yshift=-.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length},anchor=north east,inner xsep=0pt}, 
              ylabel={\normalsize $y$}, ylabel style={xshift=-.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}, anchor=north east, inner ysep=0pt}
              ]    
        
        % define the coordinates (interpolation points) for the lower boundary
        \coordinate (A) at (2,2);
        \coordinate (B) at (2.2,2.3);
        \coordinate (C) at (3,1.9);
        \coordinate (D) at (4,2.3);
        \coordinate (E) at (5,1.8);
        \coordinate (F) at (6,2);
        
        % define the coordinates (interpolation points) for the upper boundary
        \coordinate (G) at (6,6); 
        \coordinate (H) at (5,6.2);
        \coordinate (I) at (4,5.8);
        \coordinate (J) at (3,6.1);
        \coordinate (K) at (2.2,5.7);
        \coordinate (L) at (2,6);

        % draw the domain as a single closed curved that interpolates through A, B, C, D, E and F runs straight to G interpolates through H, I, J, K and L and runs again straight to A
        \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (A) to [curve through = {(B) (C) (D) (E)}] (F) to (G) to [curve through = {(H) (I) (J) (K)}] (L) to (A);

        % draw the dashed red lines
        \draw[red, dashed] (2,0) -- (A);
        \draw[red, dashed] (6,0) -- (F);
        
        % add the function name to the upper and lower boundary
        \node at (4,6.5) {$\beta (x)$};
        \node at (4,1.5) {$\alpha (x)$};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]